# Implement exponential backoff on SQS listener

Tags: java, spring, amazon-web-services, amazon-sqs

I’ve a SQS queue which has max receives value of 3 & default visibility timeout of 30 seconds.

Currently I’m listening to its messages using annotation `@SqsListener`, which works fine.

Now I want to implement exponential backoff for retries on this queue.

The only pointer I got in this direction in AWS documentation is to use [ClientConfiguration](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/general/latest/gr/api-retries.html).

But I'm not able to find any exmample on how to use it.

I thought [SimpleMessageListenerContainer](https://javadoc.io/doc/org.springframework.cloud/spring-cloud-aws-messaging/1.0.0.RC2/org/springframework/cloud/aws/messaging/listener/SimpleMessageListenerContainer.html) might provide a [setter](https://www.javadoc.io/static/org.springframework.cloud/spring-cloud-aws-messaging/2.2.0.RELEASE/org/springframework/cloud/aws/messaging/config/SimpleMessageListenerContainerFactory.html#setBackOffTime-java.lang.Long-) to apply backoff strategy, but it just provides to add a timer.

If there any examples to guide how to add backoff in spring in SQS listener, that will be great.

Comment: What do you mean by "max receives value"?

Comment: @jarmod, it is the number of times that a message can be received before being sent to a dead-letter queue.

Comment: Ah, the max receive count on the redrive policy. OK, thanks. I wasn't sure what you were referring to. My fault.

Answer (score 0):

```
  @Value("${sqs.retryIntervalInMillis:1000}")
  private long retryIntervalInMillis;

  @Bean
  public AmazonSQSAsync amazonSQSAsync(final ClientConfiguration clientConfiguration) {
    return AmazonSQSAsyncClientBuilder.standard()
        .withEndpointConfiguration(new AwsClientBuilder.EndpointConfiguration(sqsUrl, region))
        .withCredentials(new DefaultAWSCredentialsProviderChain())
        .withClientConfiguration(clientConfiguration)
        .build();
  }

  @Bean
  public ClientConfiguration sqsClientConfiguration() {
    return new ClientConfiguration()
      .withRetryPolicy(RetryPolicy.builder()
        .withBackoffStrategy((originalRequest, exception, retriesAttempted) -> retryIntervalInMillis)
        .withHonorDefaultBackoffStrategyInRetryMode(true)
        .build());
  }

  @Bean
  public SimpleMessageListenerContainerFactory simpleMessageListenerContainerFactory(final AmazonSQSAsync amazonSQSAsync) {
    SimpleMessageListenerContainerFactory msgListenerContainerFactory =
        new SimpleMessageListenerContainerFactory();
    msgListenerContainerFactory.setAmazonSqs(amazonSQSAsync);
    return msgListenerContainerFactory;
  }
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).